# Totals Column MDX Query

Tags: sharepoint-2013, mdx

I'm new to MDX and I have a small problem, hopefully they can help me.

I have an Analytic Chart with the following query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Articulo].[Art_Linea].[ Aggregation] AS 
    Aggregate({[Articulo].[Art_Linea].&[3M],[Articulo].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]}) 
   ,SOLVE_ORDER = 0 
SELECT 
    Hierarchize
    (
      {
        [Almacen].[Alm_Nombre].&[MATRIZ]
       ,[Almacen].[Alm_Nombre].&[TOLUCA]
      }
    )
  * 
    {
      [Measures].[Val]
     ,[Measures].[Disponible]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    {
      [Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[3M]
     ,[Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]
    }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Inventario]
WHERE 
  [Articulo].[Art_Linea].[ Aggregation]
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE
 ,CELL_ORDINAL
 ,FONT_FLAGS
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,BACK_COLOR;
```

Which returns the following grid:

[Analytic Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixDbL.png)

I would like to add a "Totals" column with the sum of the "Val" and "Disponible" measures of the columns "MATRIZ" and "TOLUCA" for each "Articulo LCD".

Could you guide me in how to do it? I'm not sure how to implement the "Sum" function.

Beforehand thank you very much.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Articulo].[Art_Linea].[ Aggregation] AS 
    Aggregate({[Articulo].[Art_Linea].&[3M],[Articulo].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]}) 
   ,SOLVE_ORDER = 0 
  MEMBER [Articulo].[LCD].[All].[3M+Bendix] AS //<<you might need to play around here - maybe this is correct name?: [Articulo].[LCD].[All].[Art_Linea].[3M+Bendix]
    Sum
    (
      {
        [Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[3M]
       ,[Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]
      }
    ) 
SELECT 
    Hierarchize
    (
      {
        [Almacen].[Alm_Nombre].&[MATRIZ]
       ,[Almacen].[Alm_Nombre].&[TOLUCA]
      }
    )
  * 
    {
      [Measures].[Val]
     ,[Measures].[Disponible]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    {
      [Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[3M]
     ,[Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]
     ,[Articulo].[LCD].[All].[3M+Bendix]  //<<you might need to play around here - maybe this is correct name?: [Articulo].[LCD].[All].[Art_Linea].[3M+Bendix]
    }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Inventario]
WHERE 
  [Articulo].[Art_Linea].[ Aggregation];
```

Although I'm a little unsure of the purpose of the Aggregation member - so maybe just the following?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Articulo].[LCD].[All].[3M+Bendix] AS //<<you might need to play around here - maybe this is correct name?: [Articulo].[LCD].[All].[Art_Linea].[3M+Bendix]
    Sum
    (
      {
        [Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[3M]
       ,[Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]
      }
    ) 
SELECT 
    Hierarchize
    (
      {
        [Almacen].[Alm_Nombre].&[MATRIZ]
       ,[Almacen].[Alm_Nombre].&[TOLUCA]
      }
    )
  * 
    {
      [Measures].[Val]
     ,[Measures].[Disponible]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    {
      [Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[3M]
     ,[Articulo].[LCD].[Art_Linea].&[Bendix]
     ,[Articulo].[LCD].[All].[3M+Bendix]  //<<you might need to play around here - maybe this is correct name?: [Articulo].[LCD].[All].[Art_Linea].[3M+Bendix]
    }
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Inventario];
```

Comment: Thanks for two things: for indenting my code and showing me more clarity in the MDX language and for showing me how I can use the "SUM" function.

What I want to do is a sum of the measures "Val" and "Disponible" of all columns for each of the rows, something like this:

http://i.imgur.com/7vR06rC.png

How could I do it?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Regards!

Comment: And indeed, the "Aggregation" member was left over in my code! Thanks!